# Permalink Short code showing unnecessary link text inside the loop

Tags: posts, loop, permalinks, urls, archives

Recently I need Help regarding this permalink shortcode

```
function my_permalink(){
ob_start();
the_permalink();
return ob_get_flush();}

add_shortcode('my_permalink','my_permalink');
```

for this, I get a shortcode [my_permalink], it's working fine

**But the problem is when I use this shortcode on my WordPress Posts, Pages, CPT, CT or any custom Archive Page it shows me some unnecessary link text which is at top of the loop and also it does not include any HTML tag**

I am showing the screenshot and the link appearing position in the posts

Code:

```
    </div>
        <div class="entry-content">
            https://careerfeed.net/jobs/kfri-recruitment-2021-for-1-project-assistant/<div class="wprt-container"><p>KFRI Recruitment 2021 for 1 Project Assistant Applications are invited from eligible candidates for the post of one <b>Project Assistant </b>under the project KFRI/RP 823/2021 entitled “Ecological studies on post restoration success of threatened plants in situ.&#8221;</p>
https://careerfeed.net/jobs/kfri-recruitment-2021-for-1-project-assistant/
<p>&nbsp;</p>
```

Screenshot:
The URL appears:

https://prnt.sc/15jcg6d

I just paste the shortcode:

https://prnt.sc/15jckza

Inside inspect Elements:

https://prnt.sc/15jct1q

Comment: You know you could just use `add_shortcode( 'my_permalink', 'get_the_permalink' );` Since there's already a function for returning the permalink.

Answer (score 0):

`ob_get_flush` doesn't do what you think it does. You're assuming that it only ends the output buffer and returns its contents, which is incorrect, it also flushes the output buffer to the browser.

So this:

```php
return ob_get_flush();
```

Is the same as this:

```php
$content = ob_get_clean();
echo $content;
return $content;
```

Use `ob_get_clean();` instead, which erases the output buffer instead of flushing it.

Comment: I think i understood what's actually wrong with my code

Comment: I don't understand the last comment you left, can you clarify?

Comment: it's nothing , i says i was wrong with ob_get_flush(); which flushes the output buffer inside the buffer, and now it's ok I replace ob_get_flush() with ob_get_clean();

Comment: I see, if this answers your question could you mark it as the accepted answer?

Comment: Yes Sir I accept this answer, your answer was 100% current , and also make my doubt clear

Comment: @GOST I meant the green tick button under the voting controls, e.g. https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/161482/736, marking it as accepted gets us both points and stops the site listing the question in the unanswered section